# Show only the first image from a list and remove the rest using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of 5 images displaying on my site. Somehow, I want to display only the first image to indicate it is image of the week. The rest can stay with only titles. How do I use jquery to remove the rest images?

```
<ul class="wpp-list">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg"/>Image One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg"/>Image Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg"/>Image Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg"/>Image Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image5.jpg"/>Image Five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li:not(li:first) img').remove();
```

You can use this

or

```
$('.wpp-list li:not(li:first) img').remove();
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5SUwp/5/

Comment: Hi, for the rest, I just need to remove image, not the whole list. I mean keeping it like <li><a href="#">Image Two</a></li>

Comment: $('li:not(li:first) img').remove();   so.

Comment: It's nothing. When you'll think that you'll have your final answer, don't forget to close the topic in accepting the good answer. Byebye